# Updating my plugin without releasing a new version

Tags: plugin-development

Is it possible to change a file in wordpress.org repository (using SVN) without incrementing the plugin minor version?
Normally, when I change something in my plugin and want to update it in the repository, I need to increment the version and upload the plugin files under /tags folder as a new minor version.
This will also send a notification to all plugin users of a new version release.

What should be done in order to make a small change in the existing version without incrementing it and without the notification?

Answer (score 4):

yes, it's absolutely possible.

When you've done developing your plugin, you set `Stable Tag` field on `trunk/readme.txt` to, lets say 1.0.1
This value should match with `Version` field on your plugin's meta data.

Then, when you publish your plugin, you tag it with, let's say, /tags/1.0.1/

To continue development, change `Version` field on your plugin's meta data to something else. Increment it would be the better choice. But, you don't need to change your `readme.txt`. Leave `Stable Tag` intact, just change it once you are ready to publish it. And follow the previous step.

Note: This information is available on [wordpress's page](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/svn/) too.

Comment: Regarding readme.txt stable tag you wrote "just change it once you are ready to publish it". However, I wanted to update a file in the repository (because of a very minor change), without changing the stable tag.

Comment: Because as I understand, changing the stable tag forces me to increment the version which will cause the plugin users to upgrade the plugin. Isn't it right?

Comment: if you just want to update some files in trunk, then just update it. Nothing changed in your /tags/versions. But, if you want your user to also update the files, you need to increment the version. Otherwise, only new download get the update. CMIIW here

Comment: Thank you silent. The thing is that I want to update something in the readme.txt file (since it's the first plugin I host in wp repository and still learning how to write a good readme.txt file). So, for a new readme file I don;t want to increment the version.

Comment: In addition, I did try what you suggested, to simply update the files, but the repository didn't reflect the change I made in the plugin page...

Comment: Do you tag your plugin? if so, change readme.txt on that tag. Btw, can I have the name of you plugin?

Comment: Thanks! this should do it. Here's the plugin - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/plugin-test-drive/